# Change ASP Label text color after DropdownList value is changed?

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net

**Goal:** Have ASP Label text color change when an ASP Dropdown ListItem is chosen. If ListItem's value is false, then the Label's text should be red. Otherwise stay black.

**Problem:** It changes color only when the page is refreshed (or if the value is already false from the database upon original page load)

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried using .Text as well as .SelectedValue
- I've tried having this run during the DropdownList's OnSelectedIndexChanged
- Looked at other articles but they mention javascript for the SAME control, not changing color on a DIFFERENT control than what is selected (e.g. [ASP.NET Change link button color when clicked without post-back or update panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272729/asp-net-change-link-button-color-when-clicked-without-post-back-or-update-panel) )

Is this possible purely in C#/asp.net without a page refresh?
If I need to do javascript, how can I do it from the Dropdownlist to the Label?

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" height="20" width="20" CssClass="providericon"/><sup><asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" Font-Size="20px" CssClass="oval"/></sup> 
                <asp:Label ID="myLabelMid" runat="server" CssClass="professorname"/>
                <asp:DropdownList runat="server" id="ddlAvailability1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAvailability_OnSelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="dropdowns">
                    <asp:ListItem ID="LT1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem ID="RT1"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropdownList>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>          
</div>
        
<asp:Panel ID="row2" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <%--<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>--%>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="img2" runat="server" CssClass="professoricon"/><sup><asp:Label ID="L2" runat="server" Font-Size="20px" CssClass="oval"/></sup> <asp:Label ID="M2" runat="server" CssClass="professorname"/> 
            <asp:DropdownList runat="server" id="ddlAvailability2" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAvailability_OnSelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="dropdowns">
                <asp:ListItem ID="LT2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem ID="RT2"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropdownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

**CSS:**

```
.professorname {
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 55px;
}

.redtext {
    color: red;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 55px;
}
```

**C#:**

```
Page_Load(){
    myLabelMid.CssClass = (ddlAvailability1.SelectedValue == "False") ? "redtext" : "professorname";
    M2.CssClass = (ddlAvailability2.SelectedValue == "False") ? "redtext" : "professorname";
    M3.CssClass = (ddlAvailability3.SelectedValue == "False") ? "redtext" : "professorname";
}
    
protected void ddlAvailability_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DropDownList ddlSender = (DropDownList)sender;
        int professorIndex = getProviderIndex(ddlSender.ClientID);
        
}

public int getProfessorIndex(string ddlSenderClientID)
{
            int professorIndex = 0;
            switch (ddlSenderClientID)
            {
                case "ddlAvailability1":
                    professorIndex = 0;
                    myLabelMid.CssClass = (ddlAvailability1.SelectedValue == "False") ? "redtext" : "professorname ";
                    break;
                case "ddlAvailability2":
                    professorIndex = 1;
                    M2.CssClass = (ddlAvailability2.SelectedValue == "False") ? "redtext" : "professorname ";
                    break;
            }
            return professorIndex;
}
```

Comment: This link might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926663/set-different-colors-in-aspdropdownlist-items There are many ways to do what you ask using raw JavaScript or jQuery MS Ajax. Another way is to deliver JS to the client in first response/request using ClientScriptmanager https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.8 Many way to do what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

DropdownList is an **ASP.NET control** and it needs **AutoPostback** to fire the **SelectedIndexChanged** event, I just adapted your problem and the simplest solution is to use an update panel that covers the DropdownList and Label:

**ASPX Code:**

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="myLabelMid" runat="server" CssClass="professorname" Text="test"/> 
        <asp:DropdownList runat="server" ID="ddlAvailability1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAvailability1_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="dropdowns">
            <asp:ListItem ID="LT1" Text="yes"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem ID="RT1" Text="no"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropdownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**C# Code:**

```
protected void ddlAvailability1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlAvailability1.SelectedValue == "no") { myLabelMid.CssClass = "redtext"; }
    else { myLabelMid.CssClass = "professorname";}
}
```

I think that reaching the same behavior through JavScript is possible but it is a more complicated solution with an ASP.NET control, because you will need to do the validation in your function once the PostBack finishes, this can be done using `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()`.

Comment: Thanks, it works with 1 dropdown, but if I have multiple on the page it starts acting strange. I have the 3 dropdowns associated to ddlAvailability_OnSelectedIndexChanged method, which has a switch case to deatermine which dropdown was used. Should UpdatePanel and/or ContentPanel be on all 3 dropdowns?

Comment: Yes, include the other Dropdownlist and your Label in the same UpdatePanel, you should have no problems

Comment: Ok, I made that change to include them all in the updatepanel. What I notice is they work fine separately (i.e. It updates the color when using Dropdown1, OR when using Dropdown2.) But if I use Dropdown 1, then without a refresh use Dropdown2 it doesnt work. If I change Dropdown1 from True to False, then change Dropdown2 from True to False, then Dropdown1 somehow goes back to True. Trying to figure it out, because this behavior wasn't happening before I added the ScriptManager/UpdatePanel/ContentTemplate

Comment: It's weird, I don't quite understand when you say: "then without a refresh use Dropdown2", you mean without clicking?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: These controls are on the Site.Master so they appear on all pages. By refresh I meant like refresh the page, or click on another page. Basically: use Dropdown1, then immediately after use Dropdown2. The dropdown I use first seems to take the current value (not selected) of the second dropdown I use (and thus the color).

Comment: I think I already understood, as the controls are in the master, then, if you leave for example one "True" and another "False" and followed by this you enter a new form (that inherits from the master) then you want the initial state? I guess instead of this the controls revert to the default options.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code.

If you use `OnSelectedIndexChanged` the DDL will trigger a PostBack and all changes made to the DOM with jQuery will be lost. You seem to know this, but I mention it just to make sure. So if you use this, make sure you bind data inside an `IsPostBack` check.

And there is no `False` in your code snippet. A ListItem is selected or not, but you use the `Value`, not the yes/no selected state.

A ListItem does not have an `ID` property.

Take a look at the snippet below for a jQuery text color change demo. Use either one, not both at the same time.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlAvailability1" CssClass="dropdowns">
    <asp:ListItem Value="">Select a Professor</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="LT1">Professor LT1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="LT2">Professor LT2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="LT3">Professor LT4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<script>
    //this changes the color to red as soon as something changes in the dll
    $('.dropdowns').bind('change', function () {
        $(this).addClass('redtext');
    });

    //this changes the color to red when anything other than the first item is selected,
    //else it becomes black again
    $('.dropdowns').bind('change', function () {
        if ($(this).prop('selectedIndex') !== 0) {
            $(this).addClass('redtext');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('redtext');
        }
    });
</script>

<style>
    .dropdowns {
        color: black;
    }

    .redtext {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

[VDWWD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64108349/4665) raised some important concerns with your code. You should also use the `AssociatedControlId` attribute on your labels to correctly associate the label element with your dropdown. This will add the `for` attribute to your labels. We  can then leverage that in javascript.

Something like the following.

```
<!-- Note the added AssociatedControlId attribute and the
     removal of OnSelectedIndexChange and AutoPostback -->
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" height="20" width="20" CssClass="providericon"/><sup><asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" Font-Size="20px" CssClass="oval" /></sup> 
                <asp:Label ID="myLabelMid" runat="server" CssClass="professorname" AssociatedControlId="ddlAvailability1" />
                <asp:DropdownList runat="server" id="ddlAvailability1" CssClass="dropdowns">
                    <asp:ListItem value="true">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem value="false">No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropdownList>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>          
</div>
        
<asp:Panel ID="row2" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <%--<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>--%>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="img2" runat="server" CssClass="professoricon"/><sup><asp:Label ID="L2" runat="server" Font-Size="20px" CssClass="oval"/></sup> <asp:Label ID="M2" runat="server" CssClass="professorname" AssociatedControlId="ddlAvailability1"/> 
            <asp:DropdownList runat="server" id="ddlAvailability2" CssClass="dropdowns">
                    <asp:ListItem value="true">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem value="false">No</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropdownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Javascript

```
let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdowns");
//Add Event Listeners
for(var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
   dropdowns[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
      //Find labels associated with control
      let labels = document.querySelectorAll("[for=" + this.id +"]");
      //toggle the redtext class on labels based on the selected value
      for(var j = 0; j < labels.length; j++) {
         labels[0].classList.toggle("redtext", this.value === "true");
      }
      //NOTE: if you know each dropdown only has one label
      //      use document.querySelectorAll and skip the loop
      //      document.querySelector("[for=" + this.id +"]").classList.toggle("redtext", this.value === "false");
   })
}
```

**NOTE** all code is untested and some debugging might be required but this should get you moving in the right direction. Also note jQuery is also an option here if you're already using it.

Comment: JonP - thank you. I tried this, but after removal of OnSelectedIndexChange and AutoPostback , it is no longer updating the value in the Database.